# Get verb url Laravel 5.1, how to request input and how to define route

Tags: laravel, input, get, routes, request

I have a url on my website which runs a postback script like follows:

```
https://example.com/postback/conversion?campaign_id={campaign_id}&campaign_name={campaign_name}&subid={subid}&payout={payout}&ip_address={ip_address}&gateway_id={gateway_id}&lead_id={lead_id}&country_iso={country_iso}&password={password}&virtual_currency={virtual_currency}
```

As you can see it uses the GET verb.  Please could someone advise me on how to request the data from this url, in the same way i might

```
$request->input('data')
```

But getting data from the url might be different?

Also, how would i define the route to my postback script?  So far I have:

```
Route::get('postback/conversion/', 'postback\PostbackController@conversion');
```

I am using Laravel 5.1

Comment: Hello. First, you should never use GET verb to pass data like passwords, IP and the like. You must use POST.  Why don't you do things the normal easy way? You create a Form and pass the data through the POST and pick them at the controller. Tell me if this approach does not suit you and why.

Comment: Hello patricio, I am working with a company who require this method to postback information to my server.  I have checked the docs with this company and the password wont show

Comment: @Lftclintonmorgan your are doing everything right. The route you have defined is correct and the data request too. What is the issue you are having?

Comment: No real issue I just wanted to double check I have defined everything correctly before the postbacks begin.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: I would say that actually having that in a URL makes no difference as to "how to fetch the content", just do the usual Input::get('password') at the Controller, in the validator

Comment: @Lft clinton morgan , Please check my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Please try with this in your route

> Route::get('/postback/(:any)', 'PostbackController@conversion');

Please check for more reference

https://github.com/laravel/docs/blob/5.1/routing.md